# Intermittent timeouts when testing with IEDriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am having a hard time trying to get tests that run fine on Chrome to run in a stable manner on IE.

I have followed the required [configuration steps](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) on Selenium's own documentation for IEDriver and I have the 32bit version of IEDriver also installed. I found the steps needed to setup the protected zones and add the registry key was all I needed to get IE to launch and for the tests to begin.

When running the tests I am often seeing intermittent time out related errors like so:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
```

I have seen some talk of just increasing timeout settings in the protractor config but this just feels like a magic number approach to me.

I am unsure what else to try right now, so thought I'd ask here to see what others may have done to help them past such issues.

One thing I did come across in a post elsewhere was how Chrome is more 'forgiving' with promises and that to get them to behave with IE, chaining `then()` callbacks on promises helped. This doesnt make sense to me, since from what I have read about the webdriver [control flow](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow) chaining like so shouldnt be required.

Can anyone out there share their experiences with testing against IEDriver and if they have ever hit these intermittent timeouts, how have you been able to resolve these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this Post:  This more about getting IE to work but maybe som e of the capability setting will help and also you need to configure your IE

[How to fix the slow sendkeys on IE 11 with Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626810/how-to-fix-the-slow-sendkeys-on-ie-11-with-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0/40627587#40627587).

Answer (score 0):

For me it became more stable, when i use Windows 10 IE, but I don't think it's relevant version with Windows 7 IE. I had simular problems on Windows 7 IE version, after a few runs my tests started slow down, and sometimes i get the same error as described. But it was half a year ago, i don't now about current versions, may be it's more stable.