# How to Fix Double Characters in Selenium and IE 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

When I send "Test" to a textbox the web page displays TTeesstt in the texbox.

Even though the web form displays the double characters it appears what is actually submitted to the web app is only the original text.

When I ran my test using IE 8 the text "Test" was inserted once.

When I upgraded to IE 11 the text was inserted very slowly. This problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626810/how-to-fix-the-slow-sendkeys-on-ie-11-with-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0).

I was trying to solve the slow Sendkeys problem and was playing around with my code to programmatically use IE or Chrome. I've backed off that code to just trying to use IE directly (InternetExplorerDriver class).

I've downloaded and installed all IE 11 cumulative updates.

I saw a post in Kaspersky labs forums about the double character problem. The posts seemed to indicate the problem is related to IBM Trusteer. I do have Trusteer installed on my personal laptop. However, the problem is occurring on a remote computer. I login to the remote computer via a VPN. While not 100% sure I don't think the remote computer has Trusteer.

Environment:
Windows 7 64-bit

InternetDriverServer 3.8.0.0, 32-bit

IE 11.9600.1886IS, Updates KB4052978
Selenium

Comment: Here's results of trying latest versions of Internet Explorer Driver with IE 11 as to whether IE is inserting double characters on my web form:  3.4.0 No   3.5.1 yes  3.7.0 yes  3.8.0 yes

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also.  I was able to fix it by adding an option to my IEDriver in my selenium code.  The option to add is:

ieOptions.EnableNativeEvents = true;

Unfortunately, that slowed my text-entry to about 1 character every five seconds. I was able to fix that by adding RequireWindowFocus = true.

My constructor now contains this code:

```
if (DriverType.IsType<InternetExplorerDriver>())

{

var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions { IgnoreZoomLevel = true, 
EnableNativeEvents = true, RequireWindowFocus = true};

Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);`

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has Selenium-Serenity

Thanks to Joshua I found solution to add in serenity.properties

```
serenity.driver.capabilities=nativeEvents:true;requireWindowFocus:true;
```