# selenium 3.8.0 - slow SendKeys on IE 11

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create automated tests of a webpage using Selenium on IE.

> Selenium Ver.: 3.8.0
>   IE Ver.:       11.248.16299.0
>   IE Driver:     IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0

While running the test, typing is veeery slow, so that the test fails on timeout.
I tried to find some solution, but wasn't very successful... Did anybody experience that?

I tried to implement advices from this [How to fix the slow sendkeys on IE 11 with Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626810/how-to-fix-the-slow-sendkeys-on-ie-11-with-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0), but it' still very slow and fails on timeout.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials?

Comment: You can also try these solutions mention here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626810/how-to-fix-the-slow-sendkeys-on-ie-11-with-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0/40627587#40627587

Answer (score 2):

For years the community has experienced this issue on the x64 version of the driver.
Please try again on the x86 version and see if the issue still occurs.

In one place of employment, I actually saw that having Lync / Skype for Business open at the same time, could even reduce the typekeys speed to one character every 2 seconds.

I think the solution is to just use the x86 version.