# BrowserStack - Incorrect SendKeys on IE11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, browserstack, selenium-iedriver

I am running a Selenium test on BrowserStack and sendkeys command is not sending the specified text to the input field. I noticed that this issue usually occurs with special characters like @, #, etc.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you share the selenium script that you wrote? Exclude your username and access key information from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known bug with IEDriver. SendKeys command doesn't work well with special characters and drops some letters from the input string.

You can refer the GitHub Issue - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/805#issuecomment-396581314

I recently found that BrowserStack has "browserstack.sendKeys" capability to overcome this.
Refer this [SendKeys on IE11](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/using-sendkeys-on-remote-IE11) article on BrowserStack

Answer (score 1):

Found **related issues** you may check -

- [How to fix the slow sendkeys on IE 11 with Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626810/how-to-fix-the-slow-sendkeys-on-ie-11-with-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0)
- https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/805
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5103